# Does effective internal resistance of batteries depend on their size? If so how?

Tags: electrical-resistance, batteries, electronics

It was asked to us by our professor- Consider the AA and AAA batteries, what do we think will happen to the internal resistance, will it increase or decrease or can we actually tell something about it?   (I can see that there should be something similar in both of them to note change in other quantities and their dependence on one another, perhaps its emf of both that's same, I am not sure)

It seems to depends on so many factors like the area of electrodes, the mobility of ions, collision time of the ions(maybe), length  of the battery etc..

**The first argument goes like this**- With increase in the size of the battery, the amount of electrolyte increases, the length of battery increases, and the area of the electrolyte increases as well, and since resistivity depends on both of them, including other factors like mobility, we go with the third option. It can't be determined!

**The second argument goes like**- The concentration of electrolyte will increase as well, which will decrease the collision time and hence more hindrance will occur in path of ions and this will be the dominating factor along with increase in length so overall internal resistance will increase.

Can someone please tell how would internal resistance change with size of the batteries? What factors will dominate?

Please if possible also attach the respective sources.

Comment: Have you derived a formula, or an approximate formula, for the resistance of a medium of resistivity $\rho$ confined between an inner cylinder of radius $r_1$, and an outer cylinder of radius $r_2$?

Comment: @PhilipWood Yes, I think I have,  does it relates to the question?

Comment: I'd have thought it does relate to the question, because in an AA or AAA cell the electrolyte could be thought of as confined between cylindrical electrodes. [You have, I hope, calculated the resistance between the inner cylinder and the outer cylinder.] You might care to read online about cell ('battery') construction. Incidentally, I see no reason why the resistivity of the electrolyte should be different between the different sizes of cell.